# empty index in pandas python

Tags: python, pandas, xml, api

I do not have any errors and I cannot understand what is wrong. here is my code:

```
def getEns(session, verbose=False):

    if verbose: print("Getting instructors")
    url = "https://my_url.fr"
    params = dict(sessionId=session, function='getResources', tree='false', category='instructor', detail='11')
    u = requests.get(url, params=params)
    arbre = ET.fromstring(u.content)
    Ens = pd.DataFrame(columns=['nom', 'type', 'vaca', 'dept', 'secretariat', 'creation', 'lastupdate', 'prenom'])
    k = 0
    for instructor in arbre.iter('instructor'):
        data = instructor.get("jobCategory").split(":")        
        jobCategory = data[0]
        secretariat = data[1].replace('(','').replace(')','') if len(data)==2 else ''     
        if(instructor.get("type") != '' or jobCategory != ''):
            Ens.loc[k,:] = {'nom': instructor.get("name"), 'type': instructor.get("type"), 'dept': jobCategory, 
                   'secretariat':secretariat, 'creation': instructor.get("creation"), 
                    'lastupdate':instructor.get("lastUpdate"), 'prenom':instructor.get('code')}
            k = k + 1
    Ens = Ens.drop_duplicates()
    Ens['creation'] = pd.to_datetime(Ens['creation'], format="%m/%d/%Y %H:%M")
    Ens['lastupdate'] = pd.to_datetime(Ens['lastupdate'], format="%m/%d/%Y %H:%M")
    Ens['vaca'] = "Historique"
    Idx = Ens.creation > datetime.datetime(2021,9,1)
    Ens.loc[Idx, 'vaca'] = "first"
    if verbose: print("Done")
    if verbose: print(Ens)
    return Ens
```

and here is the response I'm getting :

```
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [nom, type, vaca, dept, secretariat, creation, lastupdate, prenom]
Index: []
```

Any ideas on what I could be doing wrong? the api is working just fine as I can retrieve the data (in xml format) but for some reason I can't have it formatted in a DataFrame. Thanks

Comment: You are passing no data to `pd.DataFrame` - only column names.

Comment: Ens.loc is in my understanding where I'm getting all the datas to put in the right columns.

Comment: what would be a better way to add datas to the Data Frame? Also concat would be great to combine two series but here I don't know if that would solve my problem.

Comment: It is not clear why it is going astray. So I would use a print statement after `if(instructor.get ...` to ensure the condition is being met; then if so you could print the dictionary (say called mydict) you want to add to the dataframe to check the contents. You can then append to the DataFrame using `Ens.loc[k] =mydict` or use concat with mydict.

Comment: You were right the data was not passing into my DataFrame. I just rewrote my function differently.

Comment: You might want to look at the logging module which allows messages of various importance levels to be optionally switched on. Great for debugging without having print statements scattered through the code.